# MFC GetLastError return 5 (Access denied)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am building MFC Dialog Application.
I use Visual Studio 2010, MFC 2008/2010.
In my cpp file, i have some code to get info of the process. the process user name is `SYSTEM`.

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
        PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, 0); // 0 is my process id
    DWORD testerror = GetLastError();
    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
            &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, namestr, 
                sizeof(namestr)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox(L"", L"", MB_OK);
    }
    CloseHandle();
```

Result is displaying MessageBox, because handle is NULL.
I get GetLastError() and it return 5 ( Access is denied).
I dont know why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: FormatMessage() will map GetLastError()'s integer return into a more informative error description. That might help you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx)? It looks like you can't access the System process in this fashion.

Comment: In `0 is my process id`, what does "my" mean? Is it the ID of another process or the current process? In the latter case, you don't need to open the process at all, you can just use [`GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @acraig5075: i got result of func GetlastError() and i had got meaning of error code 5. Its Access denied. Now i just want to fix it :(

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees: yes yes. I can't Access the System process. Can u help me? Please! Thanks

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: sorry, its the system id. I mean, 0 is one of the System process id i want to get info. Id 0 is just for test.

Answer (score 1):

The `system idle process` and some other system process is not allowed to get their info.

The system idle process (ID 0) is included in the snapshot under the name [System Process], you can't open a handle for it as the documentation for OpenProcess specifically says:

`If the specified process is the System Process (0x00000000), the function fails and the last error code is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. If the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS processes, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED because their access restrictions prevent user-level code from opening them.`

Comment: Humh, so that's my problem. Seem proccesses have id is 0 and 4 is not permit to get info. Its that's true?

Comment: thanks :). 
So, with some orther system processes , i do like that to get information of processes. Project -> MyProject Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File -> UAC Excution Level -> change "asInvoler" to "requireAdministrator". And it work. 
I confuse, dont know have another way to config( by command, not config by hand). Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you can post another question on stackoverflow about this UAC. :)